# How do I let game maker know that recieved json data is an array?

Tags: networking, python, game-maker

In python I created an array called `lobbyList = ["Awesome","Funny","Epic"]`

I sent this array to Game maker studio 1.4 using JSON, I made a variable called RecievedData and made the following script

```
var name = argument0;
var data = argument1;

RecievedData = json_decode(data);
show_message(RecievedData); //Let's me know data has been recieved
```

I can recieve data fine, but when I `show_message(RecievedData)` it returns 4, when I do `show_message(data)` it gives me a string of `["Awesome","Funny","Epic"]`

So how do I tell game maker that this is an array and not just a number or string? I want to draw this array coming from the server into a lobby list but for the life of me, I can't figure out how say this is an array.

Comment: In your case `RecievedData` contains `ds_list` data structure. For example, try `show_message(RecievedData[| 1])`, it would show `Awesome`.

Comment: Prints out undefined instead of Awesome

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about `default`. Should be `var d=RecievedData[? "default"]; show_message(d[| 1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Fixed my problem, my dad helped me after reading a lot about ds maps and lists in the manual.

```
var name = argument0;
var data = argument1;

show_message(data);

resultMap = json_decode(data);
global.lobbyList = ds_map_find_value(resultMap,"default");


listLength = ds_list_size(global.lobbyList);
    show_message(listLength);
```